# how overlapping subnet in 2 SA in strongswan determine which tunnel to go?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vpn, ipsec, strongswan

i have 2 tunnels of ikev1, with overlapping in leftsubnet and rightsubnet ,how the packet that send know to which tunnel it  forward to tunnel  first_4a010003 whay is that and how i decide i nwhch tunnel the packet will forward?
my configuration is :

```
# cat /etc/ipsec.conf
conn %default
        keyexchange=ikev1
        authby=secret
        type=tunnel
        include ipsec.*.conf
conn second_4a010001
        left=50.50.50.11 #
        leftsubnet=20.20.20.0/28 
        right=50.50.50.50
        rightsubnet=30.30.30.0/28 
        esp=aes128gcm64-aes128gcm128-aes128gcm96-modp2048 
        lifetime=9999s 
        lifebytes=313032704
        auto=route 
conn first_4a010003
        left=10.10.10.11 
        leftsubnet=20.20.20.0/24 
        right=10.10.10.10 
        rightsubnet=30.30.30.0/24
        esp=aes128-sha1-modp2048 
        lifetime=8000s 
        lifebytes=313032704 
        auto=route
```

when is send packet to 30.30.30.30 to which tunnel it will go?

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         172.17.235.1    0.0.0.0         UG    1      0        0 eth0
10.10.10.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
20.20.20.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth5
50.50.50.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

# ip route
default via 172.17.235.1 dev eth0  proto none  metric 1 notify
10.10.10.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.10.10.11
20.20.20.0/24 dev eth5  proto kernel  scope link  src 20.20.20.20 linkdown
50.50.50.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 50.50.50.11
172.17.235.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.17.235.236
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's decided by the outbound IPsec policies and their priorities. You can see those with the `ip xfrm policy` command. When installing such policies, strongSwan uses higher priorities (lower numeric values) for more specific policies. For example, a packet addressed to `30.30.30.1` will use the SA created for the **second_4a010001** connection (as long as the source address lies in `20.20.20.0/28`) because `/28` subnets will result in a higher priority than `/24` subnets.

However, packets addressed to `30.30.30.30` will use the SA created with the other connection because that address is not part of the `/28` subnet.

Comment: thank's a lot , is there a way of binding  ip xfrm policy rule with a conn or a SA or just by address ?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i mean instead of making policy that is based on ip address  how to make the conn for example first_4a010003 always have better  priority when a pakcet is sent to 30.30.30.0 even thou conn second_4a010001 has the better 30.30.30.0/28 prefix ?

Comment: You can't with ipsec.conf, but with [swanctl.conf](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Swanctlconf) and newer strongSwan releases the priority of policies may be configured manually.